# iOS App > Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint

Tags: ios, iphone, freeswitch, restcomm

I'm using **RestComm sdk** with **freeSWITCH sdp** in iOS app,
and I'm trying to call user A to user B,
**calling connection successfully** in both device but I'm receiving call using below function:

**- (IBAction)tappedOnAnswer:(id)sender {

```
if (self.connection != nil) {

    [self.connection accept:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
                                                        forKey:@"video-enabled"]];
}
```

}**

**but getting Error:** {
      "NSLocalizedDescription" : "Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint."
    }

**How to solve this issue?**
Please help me how to receive call using RestComm sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj, the issue seems to be that the incoming call doesn't use webrtc for media (remember that Restcomm iOS SDK only supports webrtc for media). Can you verify that?